# File download incomplete when application killed or destroy

Tags: java, android

When I am downloading a file from the server if suppose I killed or destroy the application means it will download only half of data how to resume download when application open or how to delete incomplete data in the file.

Any ideas?

```
private void downloadBookDetails(String pMainFolder, String pFileName, String pDownloadURL) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Coming to this downloadBookDetails ");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(pDownloadURL);
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setReadTimeout(5000);
        ucon.setConnectTimeout(10000);


        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);

        File directory = new File(pMainFolder, pFileName);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
        }


        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Add Network Error.
        Log.e(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DownLoad Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) for downloads in your app. This will automatically handles all the things for you. Which is a system service that can handle long-running HTTP downloads.

**UPDATE**

If you want to download the file by your own then you can use it like below:

```
@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user 
    // presses the power button during download
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
         getClass().getName());
    wl.acquire();

    try {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                    
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/"+fileName);
            int downloaded=0;
            if(file.exists()){
                downloaded=(int) file.length();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (int) file.length() + "-");
            }
            else{
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report 
            // instead of the file


            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength()+(int)file.length();
            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();      
            if(downloaded>0){
                output = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            }
            else{
                output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = downloaded;
            int count;
            mProgressDialog.setMax(fileLength/1024);
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled())
                    return null;
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int)total/1024);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            wl.release();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }        
}
```

Comment: hi Rahul , in my app i am not using API the data coming from CMS(content management system

Comment: paste your downloadURL .

Comment: //Download File Name
    public static final String BOOK_MAIN_IMAGE = "BookMainImage";
    public static final String BOOK_MAIN_AUDIO = "BookSound";
    public static final String PAGE_IMAGE = "PageImage";
    public static final String PAGE_AUDIO = "PageAudio";
    public static final String PAGE_TEXT = "PageText";

Comment: this is what contentfull Api URL

Comment: what is the value of **pDownloadURL**?

Comment: http://assets.ctfassets.net/j597ek102725/6puSxe5gEEigAyUyc8Mu0a/e696a5b2d1db3795216104642d8b1161/Page.txt

Comment: where did it break?